# Domain Access + Domain i18n = Site names not translating in other languages?

Tags: i18n-l10n, domain-access

I have 4 languages and 2 domains: site.com site.eu
I set up languages in these domains like:

- site.com - english (default)

  br.site.com - brazilian

  site.eu - german

  fr.site.eu - french

When I try to type Site Name for french and brazilian it does not save the line. but it save Slogan.
So Drupal use default site name of default language for both Brazilian And French sites: br.site.com and fr.site.eu

this instruction did not help me http://reyero.net/drupal/internationalization_domain_access_multilingual_variables_for_each_domain

There are Realms information that I've found. But how to configure correct I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the "[Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)" module. And even though you didn't explicitely mention it, you also use the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. If my assumptions are correct, then be aware of what's mentioned on the project page of the "[Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)" module:

> If you use the contributed [i18n module suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), you should use the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module instead of the provided Domain Configuration and Domain Settings modules.

Therefor I think you should try the [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module, to check if it fixes you issue.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed with this:

1. add all the domains you have to the domains: so not only site.com and site.eu but also br.site.com and fr.site.eu and all others subdomains
2. set up in the every domain settings need name.

and think i've found one more method:

in domain access settings admin/structure/domain/settings there is checkbox:
Override site name with name of domain.

when i uncheck this the site name translations started work!